# How do I insert an image before a TEXT_NODE using HTML DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

I am seemingly stuck with this innocuous task. Once a TEXT_NODE is found, I am trying to insert an image tag formed dynamically.

So for example, if the TEXT_NODE is the following within a paragraph, `<p> This is a TEXT_NODE </p>`, I want it to be `<p> <img src="...">This is a TEXT_NODE</p>`.

This is my code snippet:

```
if (nodex.nodeType == 3) { // Node.TEXT_NODE
   [...]
   var DOM_img    = content.document.createElement("img");
   DOM_img.src    = "http://www.somesite.com/pix/" + bPix + ".gif";
   DOM_img.height = '27';
   DOM_img.width  = '19';
   DOM_img.hspace = '1';
   DOM_img.vspace = '5';
   DOM_img.alt    = bAlt;

   // This is where I want to insert the HTML IMG Tag
}
```

I tried all of the following (and some more) following answers to various similar questions on SO- nothing seems to be working.

```
   //nodex.insertBefore(DOM_img, nodex);
   //nodex.parentNode.appendChild(DOM_img);
   //nodex.parentNode.innerHTML = html_for_DOM_img;
   //nodex.innerHTML = html_for_DOM_img;
```

If I do `content.document.body.appendChild(DOM_img);` that works but the image is expectedly placed elsewhere (which I do not want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one you haven't tried... ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qLfdn/))

```
nodex.parentNode.insertBefore(DOM_img, nodex);
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the answer - it worked perfectly. However, even more thanks for showing me the site http://jsfiddle.net. I could have saved a lot of time had I known that site earlier.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this

```
var oPara = document.getElementById( 'para' ),
    oImg = document.createElement( 'img' ),
    oTxt = document.createTextNode( 'Hello World!' );

oImg.setAttribute( 'src', 'sample.jpg' );
oPara.appendChild( oImg );
oPara.appendChild( oTxt );
```

This requires HTML element `p` or `div` defined with id `para`.

Comment: Thanks but as I showed in my example, my `<p>` did not have an `id`. Take a look into the answer above from canon. That's the right way.